# Energy paradox in classical electrodynamics?

Tags: electromagnetism, lienard-wiechert

Consider two massive charged objects at rest with a large horizontal distance $d$ between them (object $1$: mass $m_1$, charge $q_1$ and object $2$: mass $m_2$, charge $q_2$).

I apply a constant vertical force $\vec{f_1}$ upwards to object $1$ so that it gains an acceleration $\vec{a_1}=\vec{f_1}/m_1$.

The total amount of power $P_1$ that object $1$ radiates is given by the [Larmor formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larmor_formula):

$$P_1=\frac{2}{3}\frac{q_1^2 a_1^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0c^3}.\tag{1}$$

Now assume that object $2$ is constrained to move only in the vertical direction. If the horizontal distance $d$ between the objects is large then only the "radiative" part of the [Lienard-Wiechert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li%C3%A9nard%E2%80%93Wiechert_potential) electric field due to object $1$ can do any work on object $2$. The vertical force $\vec{f_2}$ acting on object $2$ is given by:

$$\vec{f_2}=-\frac{q_1q_2}{4\pi\epsilon_0c^2d}\vec{a_1}.\tag{2}$$

The power received by object $2$, $P_2$, is given by:

$$P_2=\vec{f_2}\cdot\vec{v_2}.\tag{3}$$

The equation of motion of object $2$ is given by:

$$m_2 \frac{d\vec{v_2}}{dt}=\vec{f_2}.\tag{4}$$

As the vertical force $\vec{f_2}$ is constant and the object $2$ is initially at rest then integrating Eqn.(4) gives:

$$\vec{v_2}=\frac{t\vec{f_2}}{m_2}.\tag{5}$$

Substituting Eqn.(2) and Eqn.(5) into Eqn.(3) we find that the power $P_2$ received by object $2$ is given by

$$P_2=\Big(\frac{q_1q_2}{4\pi\epsilon_0c^2d}\Big)^2\frac{a_1^2t}{m_2}.\tag{6}$$

Finally, the ratio of the power received by object $2$, $P_2$, to the power emitted by object $1$, $P_1$, is given by

$$\frac{P_2}{P_1}=\frac{3}{2}\frac{q_2^2t}{4\pi\epsilon_0cd^2m_2}.\tag{7}$$

Thus eventually object $2$ receives more power than the total power emitted by object $1$.

What's gone wrong? :)

**Additional calculation**

I've put some numbers into the equations in such a way that the final velocities $v_1$, $v_2$ remain non-relativistic and only the radiative part of the Lienard-Weichert field from object $1$ to object $2$ is significant:
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
a_1&=&1.0\times10^{10}\ \hbox{m/s^2}\\
q_1&=&1.0\ \hbox{C}\\
q_2&=&1.0\times10^{10}\ \hbox{C}\\
m_2&=&1.0\ \hbox{kg}\\
\Delta t&=&2.5\times10^{-5}\ \hbox{s}\\
d&=&7.5\times10^{6}\ \hbox{m}\\
c\Delta t/d&=&1.0\times10^{-3}\\
v_1/c&=&8.3\times10^{-4}\\
v_2/c&=&1.1\times10^{-7}\\
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
The energy $E_1$ radiated by object $1$ from $t=0$ to $t=\Delta t$ is:
$$E_1=5.5\times10^{-1}\ \hbox{Joules}$$
The energy $E_2$ received by object $2$ from $t=d/c$ to $t=d/c+\Delta t$ is:
$$E_2=5.5\times10^{2}\ \hbox{Joules}$$
Therefore object $2$ receives a thousand times more energy than was emitted by object $1$.

**Unphysical assumption**

The electrostatic energy of body 2 must be at least $q_2^2/4\pi\epsilon_0d=10^{23}$ Joules. This is greater than the rest mass energy of body 2 which equals $m_2c^2=10^{16}$ Joules. This seems to show that my argument is unphysical and therefore not a paradox.

Comment: I think probably this is just a problem of you not using time dependent formulas & propagation delays, but it is also possible that there is a problem with you not including relativistic effects. The Larmor formula was derived from the Lienard-Wiechert potentials and Maxwell's equations conserve energy, so the claim that energy is not conserved here actually explodes into a claim like “vector calculus is inconsistent” which I think is larger than you think you're claiming. So, worth working it out in full detail rather than in sketch form.

Answer (score 1):

In answer to the last question -- many things, IMHO

1. Be more careful about forces and accelerations, at high enough speeds constant force will not lead to further constant gains in speed. Also I would suggest not working with some fictitious forces. You are accelerating charges, so let your external force will be supplied by electric field. Less chance to end up with unphysical situation.
2. You said that distance between objects is large, so why are you using what looks like electrostatic formula to compute the force on charge 2? The logical chain is $q_1$ generates electromagnetic field $\to$ electromagnetic field propagates $\to$ electromagnetic field acts on $q_2$
3. What about the electromagnetic field generated by $q_2$ and how it acts on $q_1$?
4. What about recoil due to electromagnetic field? It carries momentum, so it will create a 'drag'?
5. Careful about 'eventually' statements. You have some unspecified force and you are using non-relativistic formulae. They will only work at low speeds. To get to 'eventually' your treatment has to be relativistic.

A proper way of doing this would be to write Lagrangian for two charges and an external constant electric field, add your constraints as Lagrange multipliers. Then derive coupled differential equations for the motion of two charges. Probably you will also have differential equations for the generated field. Then you solve all of these together. It may be possible to simplify things, but you will have to state carefully under which conditions such simplifications apply.

And use relativistic Lagrangians for the particles.

Forces will not be necessary in such treatment

Comment: Regarding point 2: I'm not using the electrostatic component that goes like $q_1/4\pi\epsilon_0d^2$ but rather the radiative component that goes like $q_1a_1/4\pi\epsilon_0c^2d$.

Comment: radiative components propagate. where is the retarded time in your expression?

Comment: Ok - I left the propagation time delay out.

Comment: Retarted time includes temporal and spatial dependencies. You can't leave it out without justification, what you have for your electric field is not a solution of Maxwell's equations, and statements about 'eventually' are then completely meaningless.

Comment: These observations/objections are superficial and do not address the problem at all. The formulae and assumptions in the question are standard and justified, retardation is of course present in retarded field theory where Larmor's formula is derived but it just isn't relevant here as the problem occurs even if acceleration $a_1$ is constant and the problem occurs sooner (for numbers stated in the question) than any reaction from body 2 can reach the body 1.

Comment: @JánLalinský, if one looks to find/resolve paradoxes in a theory as well established as classical electrodynamics+kinematics, one has to cross all the t's, so no my arguments are not superficial. At least not all of them. The core of what I said is 'do it properly', starting from Lagrangian, and going to equations of motion. I think this is a better approach than trying to save a bad analysis by patching holes in it.

Comment: @JánLalinský, and don't use forces between charges when working with electrodynamics. Charges create fields, charges interact with fields. Having charges interact with each other can lead to situations where momentum is missing, because it has been carried off by the propagating field.

Comment: @Cryo you can answer any question about internal consistency this way, oh just do it more carefully. Sometimes that is warranted, I replied this way some times here, but it is not warranted here, the question is very clear and there are no obvious problems with the calculation presented. The resolution, I believe, is to understand what Larmor's formula represents and that is it not applicable to this case, not "redo the calculations with more care".

Comment: Re "don't use forces between charges when working with electrodynamics" Why not? What is wrong with forces in electromagnetic theory? Lorentz forces is what enables us to derive energy transfer from EM energy to kinetic energy of matter in the first place.

Comment: @JánLalinský, to understand Larmor formula properly you need to do same order of magnitude of work as to solve this problem, so why bother with the latter at all? Also, I did not simply say 'do it better'. I listed what needs to be added to do this question better.

Comment: @Cryo I do not understand your point regarding Larmor formula and "why bother". The question is about how to resolve the apparent contradiction,. I have answered that in my answer below.

Comment: @JánLalinský, Lorent'z force can be derived by coupling EM Lagrangian with that of a free particle. Energy can be defined as quantity conserved as a result of invariance of Lagrangian with respect to temporal translations. Nothing wrong with forces as such, but you have to remember that charges don't 'push' each other, they 'push' fields. This breaks the analogy with simple mechanics and can lead to 'paradoxes'

Comment: @JánLalinský, I also provided an answer. Drop forces, focus on equations of motion, make treatment relativistic (or develop assumptions as to why you can get away with non-relativistic treatment), use proper solutions for electromagnetic fields, *then* check if you have a paradox.

Answer (score 1):

Your calculations are correct, *total* Larmor's power radiated by body 1 is much lower than power of impressed radiation force due to 1 acquired by 2. That it, is it higher not right from the start of interaction (because impressed power is 0 when body 2 has 0 speed) but after some time. We can derive this time from your formulae to be

$$
t^* = \frac{\frac{2}{3}m_2 c^2}{F_C c}
$$
where $F_C$ is Coulomb force of charged body 2 on hypothetical charged body of the same charge separated by distance $d$. Thus $t^*$ is the time needed for the Coulomb force of the body 2 to impress energy $m_2c^2$ to hypothetical body of same charge moving with speed of light away from body 2.

In usual circumstances charge available on single body is very low and energy $m_2c^2$ is very high, so this time is extremely long. Your time $\Delta t$ can be very low because you assume extremely high value of $q_2$ and extremely low value for $m_2$. Maximum net charge we can concentrate on an isolated body of diameter 1m on Earth is probably not bigger than 1e-3 C. Even if this weighted only 1kg the time $t^*$ comes out around 10 billion years.  Even if we shorten the distance $d$ to 10m, the time is 26 days. So it is hard to observe this kind of effect. Further decrease of distance will be hard as the repelling force becomes very high.

Larmor's formula gives net EM energy flowing out of accelerated charge body *provided* there are no other charges anywhere near the region.

In your example, there *is* such a charged body: the body 2. This makes Larmor's formula derivation assumptions invalid. Total EM field is sum of fields of 1 and 2 and because body 2 is charged, total EM field in its vicinity is much higher than it would be were the body 2 absent. That's why the body 2 is able to acquire much more energy than Larmor's formula would suggest is available. Much more energy is available, because body 2 is charged and has its own strong electric and magnetic field. This fact is entirely ignored by Larmor's formula derivation.

Larmor's formula is pretty much useless when analyzing interaction of charged bodies and energy transfer between them. One must go back to analysis of  mutual EM forces as you have done.

Comment: What happens if body 2, with a large charge $q_2$, is enclosed by a very massive charged spherical shell with charge $-q_2$? In that case body 1 would not feel any static field from body 2 and therefore Larmor's formula would be valid for the radiated power from body 1.

Comment: I do not follow. Whether body 1 experiences force due to 2 is irrelevant. The time $\Delta t$ given above is so short that radiation field from 2 does not reach 1.

Comment: In the original setup, before body 1 moves (i.e. $t<0$), there is a static field due to body 2 at the location of body 1. I'm not sure if this causes a problem for the application of Larmor's formula for body 1 when the acceleration is applied to it (i.e. $t>0$). My point was that one could take away this static field by screening body 2 with an equal and opposite charge around it. I don't know if that helps.

Comment: The static field of 2 acting on 1 can be made arbitrarily small, just increase the distance $d$. This field does change the Poynting vector near the body 1 but if the field of 2 is very small there, it changes the net Poynting power flowing out of the particle negligibly. However, the field of 2 is not negligible near the body 2 so there the change in Poynting vector is substanial, so the Larmor formula is inapplicable. If body 2 is screened, then we have 3 body problem and the system becomes more complicated, it does not help the analysis.

Comment: Even with the screening sphere, the field is still strong in the space between the body 2 and the screen, so the same substantial change in the Poynting vector occurs there.

Comment: But in my analysis I only apply the Larmor formula to the radiated power from body 1. I use the Lienard-Weichert field from 1 to 2 to calculate directly the absorbed power into body 2 which I find is much larger than the total power radiated by body 1.

Comment: Yes I understand that and I think it is a correct result. The Larmor formula gives Poynting power leaving the region of body 1, but power transferred to kinetic energy of body 2 is bigger than that. This is possible because EM field has more energy available near body 2 than the energy that is coming from body 1. This is because energy of EM field near the body 2 isn't determined by the field of body 1 alone. Body 2 has lots of electrostatic energy nearby.

Comment: In other words, Poynting vector flux for little sphere around 1 is a different thing from Poynting vector flux for a little sphere around 2. After some time when body 2 moves with large enough speed, the flux entering 2 is bigger. There is plenty of EM energy around the body 2 to account for that. We know this because of the energy interpretation of the Poynting theorem; the work of electric field force on currents is locally accounted for by EM energy incoming from outside and decrease of EM energy inside. Larmor's formula is too simplistic to replace the Poynting theorem.

Comment: So are you saying that body 2 derives some of its kinetic energy from the action of its own EM field on itself?

Comment: No. The force that accelerates the body 2 is electric force due to body 1. So this force is doing the work so the field of 1 has to be present at position of 2. But regarding energy, kinetic energy increase per time is due to EM energy present around the body 2 and flowing into 2. The field of 1 at position of 2 creates flow of this energy into the body 2 where it changes into kinetic energy. In other words, the Poynting vector is function of both the field of 2 and field of 1 and has much greater flow than it would if total field was just that of body 1.

Comment: Another way to say this is that the *flow* of energy into kinetic energy of 2 is *due* to presence of field of 2, but the EM energy that gets transformed is not "energy of field 2", because there is no such concept even though we tend to think that way. EM energy is integral of function of total field, not sum of integrals of functions of the partial fields that contribute to that total field. In the vicinity of 2 this EM energy is much greater than what it would be if only field of 1 was present. It is much greater due to strong electric and magnetic field of 2 there.

Comment: Ok - the EM field energy is due to the total field of bodies 1 and 2 - thanks